# Comparing Month with date(MM/DD/YR)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to compare a month number with a date(MM/DD/YR) in Excel/Google Sheets?

For example, according to the screenshot, I just want to calculate the weekly time only in September and not August. I want it to be general so whatever month I choose, it will only calculate the hours for that month and not other months that is displayed on the table. I think the way to approach the problem is writing an if statement where if the DATE column starts with "9", then it will only calculate that row, and ignore the other rows that is not a 9.

I am just not sure if we can compare multiple cells to see if it matches with a certain month.

[image]

Comment: In `excel` there is a function called [MONTH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/month-function-579a2881-199b-48b2-ab90-ddba0eba86e8) which can convert a valid date into a number representing that month. Not sure if this is sufficient to solve your case?

Comment: @TerryW I have tried that where I said

    =IF([the dates] = MONTH(Sep 2019),....)

Do you know if I do that, does it only look at the month number in the dates and compares it?

Comment: why don't you read the MONTH function link I provided and try it out yourself? FYI `Sep 2019` is not a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B1:B7, MONTH(A1:A7)=8))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUMIFS` in both Excel or Google Sheets:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E8,A2:A8,">="&F10,A2:A8,"<="&EOMONTH(F10,0))
```

[image]

Adjust ranges (and make them absolute if need be)